# Asyncpg pool randomly stops responding

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, asyncpg

I use an [asyncpg](/questions/tagged/asyncpg) `Pool` for my discord.py bot but as I said in the title, it randomly stops responding. Commands that use the pool don't work, but others do, and I'm sure I close all the connections after I use them. I tried searching on google but haven't found anything

Here's how I create the pool:

```
self.pg_pool:asyncpg.pool.Pool = await asyncpg.create_pool(DSN, 
                                     max_inactive_connection_lifetime=3600.0)
```

EDIT: I thought this information isn't enough and I decided to add something.
I get no exceptions or errors.
I thought maybe it's because of the pool's lifetime and changed it to `0`(disables the mechanism) and that doesn't work

Comment: Do you see any error message in the terminal you're running the bot from?

Comment: No exceptions or errors

Answer (score 0):

I opened an issue with the developers of asyncpg and found that pool connections had to be opened with `async with pool.acquire() as conn:` for them to be correctly closed surprisingly. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It not true that one needs to acquire connections using a context manager like `async with pool.acquire() as conn`. Totally possible to `conn = await pool.acquire()`...

...That said, why would you ever want a connection to last that long? I think your question belongs to the architectural side rather than in the code itself. I cannot think of a reason to ever WANT a database connection to stay open that long.